# Please help me to determine whether it is linear !!!

Tags: linear-transformations

For T: V2->V2

T maps each point with polar coordinate (r.theta) to each point with polar coordinate (r,2theta) and T maps 0 onto itself.

Hi,

I was trying to do this by letting r= square root of x^2 + y^2 and theta=arctan(y/x)

but I failed.

can anybody please explain it?

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is not linear since $$T(1+i)=T\left({\sqrt 2} e^{i\frac{\pi}4} \right)={\sqrt 2} e^{i\frac{\pi}2} =i {\sqrt 2}$$
and: $$T(1)+T(i)=1+(-1)=0$$

Comment: I would like to know how to define T

Comment: Like T(x.y)=(y.x) something like that

Comment: If $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, then:$T(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(\cos 2 \theta, \sin 2 \theta)$ where $\cos \theta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $\sin \theta = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $T(0,0)=(0,0)$

Comment: would you mind explaining what it means by "T maps 0 onto itself? does that mean that T(0)=0?

Comment: Yes! its this exactly!

Comment: So T maps 0 onto itself means that only 0 can make T 0. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Yes $T(0)=0$. if you want $T(0,1)$ then you transform on a complexe number $(0,1)=0+1.i=i$, you write it withe the trigonometric or exp form say :$re^{i\theta}$, her : $i=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$, then $T(0,1)$ is represented by the complexe number $re^{2i\theta}=1.e^{i\pi}=-1$ who as complex number represent the point $(-1,0)$ then $T(0,1)=(-1,0)$

Comment: but if x and y are zero, then denominato of cos and sin would be zero? is it possible in this case?

Comment: For this reason, the case of $(0,0)$ was treated separately: $T(0,0)=(0,0)$. In the definition above $0$ means  $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

$T$ is surjective but not injective.  For a linear transformation from a finite-dimensional vector space to itself, this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

We can deduce that $T$ is not linear because
$$
T[(1,0)] + T[(1,\pi)] = [(1,0) + (1,0)] = (2,0)
$$
But
$$
T[(1,0) + (1,\pi)] = T[0] = 0
$$